# Dummit and Foote 14.2.4: Let $p$ be a prime. Determine the elements of the Galois group of $x^p -2$

Tags: galois-theory

Dummit and Foote 14.2.4: Let $p$ be a prime. Determine the elements of the Galois group of $x^p -2$.

My instinct tells me this has to be related to the dihedral group with order relating to $p$, but I'm not too sure where to start. I'm not wanting a whole solution, but rather a hint as to where to start.  The splitting field is $\mathbb{Q} (2^{\frac{1}{p}}\zeta ^i _p)$, but how should this relate? Can you give me some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Prove that the splitting field is $\Bbb Q(2^{1/p}, \zeta_p)$ with degree $p(p-1)$. (Hint: $p$ and $p-1$ are coprime.)
2. Look at what an automorphism can do to those two generators. (Hint: any element must be sent to itself or one of its conjugates.)
3. Define an injection from the Galois group to some concrete group. (Hint: It won't be the dihedral group because the field has degree $p(p-1)$.)
4. Use cardinalities to show that it is a bijection.

Comment: Perhaps this question is elementary and I'm missing something obvious, but why can't it be isomorphic to $D_8$?

Comment: It says $x^p-2$ not $x^4-2$.

Comment: Forgive me. I didn't mean the dihedral group of order $8$. I meant the dihedral group of some other order. (I suppose $D_{p(p-1)}$)

Comment: It might be, just not naturally.

Comment: I have determined that we can uniquely define the automorphisms by $\sigma (2^{\frac{1}{p}}) = 2^{\frac{1}{p}} \zeta _p ^{\alpha}$ and $\sigma (\zeta_p)=\zeta_p ^{\beta}$ for $\alpha,\beta \in \{ 1,...,p-1 \}$, which is the Galois group. How can I relate this to a familiar group?

Comment: @Luna145 You should also be able to take $\alpha=0$.  What do you get if you compos two of these automorphisms? Does this group have a small set of generators?